# How to improve memory footprint for iPad apps

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, memory-management

I have an iPad app that is doing really well, zero crashed reported by Apple after 5 months and 3 releases.

However occasionally the OS kills the app, my guess is for shortage of free memory.
I am not doing anything right now in the warninglowmem event.

I would like to receive some solid recommendation of what I should do to improve the memory footprint. What tools and tricks I can start using to understand where I am right now and how further I can go with the improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest starting by reading about [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) which will let you see what memory you're using and how much. In particular, the "Quick Start" and "Analysis Techniques" sections in that document should get you pointed in the right direction.

Using the "Allocations" instrument will help you watch your memory grow and tells you where it's being allocated.

You might also try using the "Leaks" instrument, which will point out if you're leaking memory (rather than just allocating too much).

Comment: Agreed, sue instruments to understand how your app is using memory, how much is actually in use, and if any is leaked. You can't fix a problem until you know what it is and there should be no need to guess if memory use is the reason for an app to be terminated.

Comment: I should hav framed my question differently - I am familiar with the tool a lot less with what to do once you know what you app sucks too much mem. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is an awesome instrumentation tool included with Xcode that lets you look for leaks.  From the Run menu choose Run With Performance Tool -> Leaks and you can see where you might be leaking memory over time.  That's a great place to start.  Next you can look at the "Allocations" tool to see how you're utilizing memory over time.  Start there and you'll learn a ton.

Comment: Wow! Our answers are amazingly similar. You get a +1 just because of that. :)